# Python API documentation of older versions of Blender

Tags: python, documentation

Where can I find Blender Python API documentation of older version/releases of Blender?
Until last weeks I came across pages of Blender 3.6 API googling for information but now, every time I try to find older documentation, I get directed to Blender 4 API.

I'm actually using Blender 3.3 and even though difference might be subtle or none at all, depending on topics, nevertheless I'd like to access specific version documentation.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply change the page address:

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html

by:

https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/index.html

or:

https://docs.blender.org/api/3.6/index.html

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way that can be useful because allow jumping directly from Blender in use at the moment to its version documentation pages.
Almost every element in the UI has an "Online Manual" button in its Right-Click Context Menu.
Clicking that button opens the default browser to a page of the right version of the documentation.

Comment: That's cool, really!